# Control Products 9102D Temperature Controller won't go below 50°F(10°C)?

Tags: equipment, temperature

So I got a dual stage controller ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0057APR3I/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057APR3I)) to hook up to a keezer that I am making. I got it wired up today and was testing it. All is well and it's working as expected except for one problem. The relay that is set to Cool won't allow me to set it below 50°F. What gives?

I checked the manual and manufacturers website and don't see any way to change this. I noticed that the "Heat" relay can go all the way down to 0°F which seems odd to me.

The manual says that this controller supports a temperature range of -40°F to 300°F so I'm hoping this isn't a bad unit or something.

Like I said, the relays switch on and off just fine, but I can't figure out how to get the cool side temperature to the correct level.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, you say that you've got a Johnson controller but then you link to a Control Products unit.

This could be several things:

First, in the extended menu functions, what is your LSL1 and LSL2 value set at? These values represent the lower limit on controller function. Set these to 32ºF (0ºC) or wherever you want.

Second, make sure your OP1 is seat to "heat" and your OP2 is set to "cool". (Or vice versa, depending on which relay is wired to which device.)

Third, make sure your SP1 and SP2 are set to the same value, your target temperature.

Fourth, make sure that LOC is set to off.

If none of those fix the problem, we might have to dig in further. It's unlikely that the device is actually broken, but it will be helpful if you go through your settings and list the value stored for each one.